# svn error - must be ancestrally related

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I am getting this error when I am merging files in two directories that share the same 
directory structure

```
/plugins/trunk/embedded-_S/Plugin/src/UPnP
/plugins/trunk/embedded-_M/Plugin/src/UPnP
```

The files under the structure of above paths are same in count and name.
When I run the command from the directory */plugins/trunk/ on my local PC:

```
svn merge https://svn.xxx.com/svn/plugins/trunk/embedded-_S/Plugin/src/UPnP/embedTags.c  embedded-_M/Plugin/src/UPnP/embedTags.c
```

I am getting following error:

> E195016: 'https://svn.xxx.com/svn/plugins/trunk/embedded-_Smart/Plugin/src/UPnP/embedTags.c@6946' must be ancestrally related to 'https://svn.xxx.com/svn/plugins/trunk/embedded-_M/Plugin/src/UPnP/embedTags.c@6945'
>   /UPnP/embedTags.c

I tried using --ignore-ancestry option then I got another error:

> E200004: Cannot merge automatically while ignoring mergeinfo

Also want to mention that the directory structure was created by another guy who has left the organisation and I am not sure whether he used ***svn copy*** to create new directories in the repo. Any help will be appreciated.